# Docker problem - Springboot container can't retrieve data from PostgreSQL container

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, networking, containers

i have very strange truble with Docker containers communication, here what i did:

1)I configured a Docker bridge network
2)I created PostgreSQL image and started it in bridge network (same of step 1)
3)I connected and filled PostgreSQL container with data using DBeaver from the host.
4)I created and started SpringBoot app container inside the bridge network. The SprigBoot app container connects correctly with PostgreSQL container.

Here's the problem: i can retrieve all data i want from PostgreSQL container using Dbeaver on same host or using my not-conteinerized SpringBoot app. But i can't retrieve data from the same PostgreSQL container using SpringBoot app container (in the same bridge network described in step 1).

It looks like SpringBoot app container can access only table's structures but it can't access data.

-I tried to modify postgresql conf allowing access from all hosts

Comment: Can you add some code/properties/error messages relevant to your issue?

Comment: @AlexeyR. hi thanks for your answer. No errors in console and configuration is ok. 
I solved the problem 15 minutes ago, here the solution:
-Even though I started the docker postgres:12 image the default postgres server that was being started was v15. I noticed this problem by doing "test connection" from DBeaver. For this reason i could see only table's structures but can't access data. I solved the problem uninstalling Postgres server v15 (I was not using it) so the default version became v12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem my own and here is the solution:

Even though I started the docker postgres:12 image the default postgres server that was being started was v15. I noticed this problem by doing "test connection" from DBeaver. For this reason i could see only table's structures but can't access data. I solved the problem uninstalling Postgres server v15 (I was not using it) so the default version became v12.